# Triple relation QueryBuilder symfony (what the hell am I doing?)

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

Let me explain how I am making things (maybe not the best way by the way).
I want to join my StoreSchedule entity (which contains a triple relation : store (which is where I stock all informations about adress, name, picture of my stores), days (the 7 days of the week) and Schedules (only strings like '09:00-22:00').

To combine thoses 3 entities, I made StoreSchedule, that has a triple relation where I cross the 3 informations. Maybe I am not explaining well, let me show you some screens.

What I already tried to do with my QueryBuilder in my repository:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQmVO.jpg

How I structured things in my StoreSchedule table :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6nKH.jpg

My Schedule table :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqqmb.jpg

Days table contains the 7 days of the week. Maybe that's obvious, maybe not.

So here's the thing, I can't figure out how to make the I need : a query that gets all content from Store and joins StoreSchedule where ID = Store.ID

I want to get days and Schedule with the ID from store.

Can I do that with query builder?

Do I have to modifiy my database? Are my relations good?

Best regards!

ps : hope I made myself clear enough..

Answer (score 0):

You make it too complicated. You can purge the days table AND StoreSchedule. Just make a many-to-one relation between Store and (Store)Schedule. Add a column "day" in your schedule table. A short integer will do if you store the number of the day. See php's [date function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

For your query (the first link) you won't need that WHERE clause. Doctrine will join the related data automatically for you.

```
    public function getAllContentStoreAndSchedule()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('st')
            ->leftJoin('st.schedule', 'sc')
            ->addSelect('sc')
            ->orderBy('st.name', 'ASC')
            ->addOrderBy('sc.day', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
        ;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, imma try that!